# Loop through multiple values within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple. I have this:

```
var loopTest = {

    Test1: {
                date : ['November 2011', 'a new date']
              },

    Test2: {
                date : 'January 2012'
              }

};
```

and using a for...in like so:

```
for(var key in loopTest) {
    $('.content').append('- '+loopTest[key].date+'<br />');
}
```

I want to make the `Test1.date` values display as separate elements. Currently, they're one string. How do I go about this?

Here's the fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aft37vq8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it short and sweet

```
for (var key in loopTest) {
    [].concat(loopTest[key].date).forEach(function(date) {
        $('.content').append('- ' + date + '<br />');
    });
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/aft37vq8/6/**

Comment: There were so many good answers, but yours is nice and short. Thank you!

Comment: Friendly IE9 and above only warning.

Comment: @stinkysGTI if you must support IE8 and below use `$.each` http://jsfiddle.net/aft37vq8/7/

Comment: Using this method, how do I go about targeting just one object? Like if I only wanted to use the data from `Test1` for example.

Comment: @Moogs I started out using `.each`, but I'm not worried about IE below 9

Comment: @Moogs Ah, ok. Thank you! I haven't used objects too much, so this has been a nice learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.isArray()` to test whether `loopTest[key].date` is an array or not. If it is, join up the dates inside with some `<br>`s and a hyphen. Else, append the string as it is.

```
for(var key in loopTest) {
    if($.isArray(loopTest[key].date)){
        var content = '- ' +  loopTest[key].date.join('<br />- ') + '<br />';
    } else {
        var content = '- ' + loopTest[key].date + '<br />';
    }
    $('.content').append(content);
}
```

Just one of the *many* ways you could go about it.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aft37vq8/5/)

Comment: @Moogs It was to simplify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the date is a array and loop through it:

```
for (var key in loopTest) {

    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(loopTest[key].date) === '[object Array]') {
        for (var i = 0; i < loopTest[key].date.length; i++) {
            $('.content').append('- ' + loopTest[key].date[i] + '<br />');
        }
    } else {
        $('.content').append('- ' + loopTest[key].date + '<br />');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var key in loopTest) {
    var date = loopTest[key].date;
    date = date.join ? date.join("<br>- ") : date
    $('.content').append('- ' + date + '<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution :)

```
var store = [];
for (var key in loopTest) {
    if (!loopTest.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    var date = loopTest[key]["date"];
    if (date.constructor === Array) {
        for (var j in date) {
            if (!date.hasOwnProperty(j)) continue;                
            store.push('<p>-', date[j], '</p>');
        }
    } else {
            store.push('<p>-', date, '</p>');
    }
}
$('.content').append(store.join(''));
```

Comment: your code is unnecessarily long. you can shorten; `store.push('<p>', date[j], '</p>');`

Comment: Very long, but interesting

Comment: good suggestion Moogs. I was going for the longest answer in the thread achievement :P